# Unable to validate a xml document against a xsd using XmlDocument.Validate in c#

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have the following XML in the XmlDocument object, its created in memory not loaded from disk.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request Attribute1="10" Attribute2="20" Attribute3="Someone">
   <Parameters />
</Request>
```

and using the following xsd to validate above XML, its loaded from disk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Request">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Parameters" />
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute name="Attribute1" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
         <xs:attribute name="Attribute2" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
         <xs:attribute name="Attribute3" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and find below the c# code used for validation, I am using .net framework 4.0

```
bool bCorrect = false;
XmlSchemaSet xmlSchemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
xmlSchemas.Add(nsAVFSale, xsdAVFSale);
xmlSchemas.Compile();

foreach (XmlSchema schema in xmlSchemas.Schemas())
    nsAVFSale = schema.TargetNamespace;

xml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xs", nsAVFSale);
if (xmlSchemas.IsCompiled && xmlSchemas.GlobalElements.Contains(new XmlQualifiedName(xml.DocumentElement.LocalName, this.nsAVFSale)))
{
    xml.Schemas = xmlSchemas;
    xml.Validate(new ValidationEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            throw e.Exception;
        else
            bCorrect = true;
     }));
}
```

I never get bCorrect = true or get the e.Exception, could you please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? (Set a breakpoint  on your `if (xmlSchemas.IsCompiled...)` line and run with debugging. Step through the code and see where it goes.)

Comment: I get xmlSchemas.IsCompiled is true and xml.Validate method is getting called, but when I put a breakpoint on the throw e.Exception or bCorrect = true line it never hits either of those breakpoints.